Doubt about derivative of the complex function in polar form: Where did I go wrong?
Let $w=f(z)=u(r,\theta)+iv(r,\theta)$ and $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then, the correct formula is
$$
\frac{dw}{dz}=e^{-i\theta}\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}
$$
But I did it in the following way
$$
\frac{dw}{dz}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}=e^{-i\theta}\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}-\frac{i}{r}e^{-i\theta}\frac{\partial w }{\partial \theta}
$$
Where did I go wrong? In other words, why not include $\theta$ if it is a polar coordinate?

This is a very interesting question, and I had to think hard to find a satisfactory answer !
The method used by the OP tacitly assumes that a small variation in $z$ causes variations in both $r$ and $\theta$. Actually, it is the other way around ! If you vary either $r$ or $\theta$ slightly, this causes a change in $z$ and hence in $f(z)$. Application of the chain rule for differentiation then leads to these results:
$$\frac {df}{dr} = \frac {\delta f}{\delta z} \frac{\delta z}{\delta r} = \frac {\delta f}{\delta z} e^{i\theta}$$
$$\frac {df}{d\theta} = \frac {\delta f}{\delta z} \frac{\delta z}{\delta \theta} = \frac {\delta f}{\delta z} ire^{i\theta}$$
Since both formulas are correct we can combine them as follows:
$$\frac {df}{dz} = \frac {1}{2} ( e^{-i\theta}\frac {\delta f}{\delta r} - \frac {i e^{-i\theta}}{r}\frac {\delta f}{\delta \theta})$$
We can do the same with small variations in $x$ or $y$, where we calculate the effect on $z$ and on $f$.
$$\frac {df}{dx} = \frac {\delta f}{\delta z} \frac{\delta z}{\delta x} = \frac {\delta f}{\delta z} $$
$$\frac {df}{dy} = \frac {\delta f}{\delta z} \frac{\delta z}{\delta y} = \frac {\delta f}{\delta z} i$$
As before we can combine these two expressions into a single formula:
$$\frac {df}{dz} = \frac {1}{2} (\frac {\delta f}{\delta x} - i \frac{\delta f}{\delta y})$$

@Masacroso. Thank you. Ik would argue that by applying the chain rule we can derive eqs. (1), (2), (4) and (5). We can then combine (1) and (2) into (3) and similarly (4) and (5) into (6). But in my opinion this is not obligatory. Do you agree? Or are there functions $f(z)$ where eqs. (3) and (6) are correct but the others are not?

@Masacroso. I assume that the OP meant that $f(z)$ is holomorphic. Then the derivative  of $f$ with respect to $z$ does exist, and satisfies (1), (2), (4), (5).  And hence also (3), (6).
